# Xamarin application not in iTunes App list

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin, itunes

I'm developing an application which saves a picture in a root folder. When I created the app originally in Xcode and tested it on my iPhone I could see if the picture was saved by going to iTunes -> iPhone -> Apps and select the app and you could see the shared files. But now I'm "recreating" the app in Xamarin the app doesn't show up in iTunes at all. It is on my iPhone because I tested it but it's not in the "Apps" list.

Can someone help me because it is important that I can check if the picture is saved. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should show what code you are using to save the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh, got it. Forgot to add the property "Application supports iTunes sharing" and Boolean "Yes" in Info.plist.